# How to delete word in Editor VI?

Tags: vi

I need to delete multiple words from the LIKE position in multiple lines.

sShipmentID LIKE ShipmentHEader
sDeliveryID LIKE ShipmentHEader
sCustomerID LIKE ShipmentHEader
sShiptoID   LIKE ShipmentHEader
lQuantity   LIKE ShipmentHEader

DEFINE sShipmentID
DEFINE sDeliveryID
DEFINE sCustomerID
DEFINE sShiptoID
DEFINE lQuantity

Thanks!!

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Try http://vi.stackexchange.com/